# Output formatting with FileHelpers

Tags: .net, filehelpers

I'm using [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.net/) to create fixed length files. In my model I have a double which needs to be outputted in a 0000.00 format.  Is there anyway I can specify this with FileHelpers itself or do I need to change my model to a string and do a .ToString(my_format) when creating the model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried using `FieldConverter`s from the FileHelpers library?

Maybe something like this.  This is untested, but it might get you on a working path:

```
using System;
using FileHelpers;

internal class MyDoubleConverter : ConverterBase
{
   public override string FieldToString(object from)
   {
      return ((double) from).ToString("0000.00");
   }
}

[FixedLengthRecord]
public class MyRecordType
{
   [FieldFixedLength(7)]
   [FieldConverter(typeof(MyDoubleConverter))]
   public double MyDouble;
}
```

Or this may work, and is even simpler:

```
[FixedLengthRecord]
public class MyRecordType
{
   [FieldFixedLength(7)]
   [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Double, "0000.00")]
   public double MyDouble;
}
```

But I think that will enforce the `0000.00` for both reading and writing, and I'm wouldn't know whether that works for your scenario.

Comment: for the other way you just implement StringToField method :)